# C# Simple login interface with SQL data model

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication

So i'm doing a course on C#, where i´ve been tasked to build an app for a fictive company.
In the app needs to be a login screen, i´ve been struggling with getting it to accept my correct login parameters (See code). Instead it says every entry is incorrect.

Can any of you spot the immediate issue with my code?

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        logindbEntities context = new logindbEntities();
        if (textBox1.Text!=string.Empty || textBox2.Text!=string.Empty)
        {
            var user = context.AdminLogin.Where(a => 
a.Full_name.Equals(textBox1.Text)).First();
            if (user != null)
            {
                if (user.Password.Equals(textBox2.Text))
                {
                    success s1 = new success();
                    s1.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("password is not correct");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("username is not registered");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("username & password are required");
        }
```

EDIT: Have me excused please, i´ve tried to edit the post to suit the guidelines better.

Comment: I see no SQL there, so the <sql> tag isn't really relevant. Perhaps you should have a <sql-server> tag instead.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please avoid pasting links to images of your code and/or data (see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Instead, copy the code directly into your post.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you may get the username and password into two variables from your form.

```
string username="";
string password="";
```

After you get the username and password from your form into the two variables, it's time to check it with the database.

```
var user = context.AdminLogin.Where(a => a.Full_Name.Equals(username)).First();
```

Then, check if the sequence does not contain any element, the user does not exist. You may use message box to display that it does not exists.

```
if(!user.Any()) // Show message here --user does not exist--
```

Then, if the user exist. You may check the password.

```
if(user.Password.Equals(password)) // Handle password here.
```

Comment: Thanks for replying to quickly!

Unfortunately it´s alitlte unclear to me what changes you are suggesting.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that do not include all code in the body of the question, as per Stack Overflow requirements. Such questions are likely to be closed, making your answer useless.